# Replace comma separated values with actual names

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

Hope someone can help me with this. I have a table that has column with values that either has a single value or a value that is comma separated and they're all single letter values. What I want to accomplish to be able to (at the presentation level) display the actual names for the letter values. Here's what I want

Original results

```
  PersonID    MentorList
  1           A
  2           K, L
  3           F
```

What I want

```
  PersonID    MentorList
  1           Big Brother/Big Sister
  2           Youth Motivators, Other Mentoring
  3           Gear Up
```

I've tried the following SQL statement but it's not producing the result that I want

```
  SELECT PersonID, REPLACE(REPLACE(MentorList, 'A', 'Big Brother/Big Sister'), 'B', 'Best Buddies') AS MentorList
  FROM Mentors
```

I get the following

```
  PersonID    MentorList
  1           Best Buddiesig Best Buddiesrother/Best Buddiesig Sister
  2           Youth Motivators, Other Mentoring
  3           Gear Up
```

As you can see, the query statement is replacing all the Bs with "Best Buddies" in the first row. How do I get it to work the way I want it?

Thanks in advace...

Comment: First things first. Did you designed MentorList column? If you had MentorNames table and relationships with Mentors table it would be much better way and you wont need to replace anything or store "encoded" data with cammas

Comment: Consider Reniuz comment, you can also use a SELECT CASE statement to do replacement

Comment: @Reniuz is right use a key table for that but if you want to get result right now, do the replace on the select and not on the where

Comment: @Bayeni CASE statement wont work on comma separated record.

Comment: Reniuz, no I did not design the MentorList column...Bayeni, I've also explored the SELECT CASE statement but got the same results

Comment: @W8Developer Must it be done in SQL? Why not just get the list in .Net and process it there?

Comment: @Liran - when I first created this post, I meant to put that in the  SELECT originally but don't how I mistakenly put it in the WHERE clause. Thanks for pointing that out...

Comment: In this case I consider to replace string in code before displaying it. In UI you wont display 275k rows so you need to replace only for those you displaying.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to go with chained REPLACE, then first replace each letter by something that got no chance of interfering ( such as #A, #B, ... )  then replace #A, #B , ... by the actual expanded text you want.

But why don't you have those values accessible separately ? why storing this as a concatened string ?

You probably should have  a Table Mentor with **MentorLetter** as primary key, and a field MentorFullName. Then a link table with (**MentorLetter**, **PersonId**), to be able to have more than Mentor per Person.

Good luck.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing but I wasn't the one who originally designed the table (that has over 275K rows)...

Comment: If you don't want to touch the current tables structure, you can create a view for that. Probably not better in term of performances, but will make your queries look less ugly.

Comment: I mean by adding a custom Table Value function that returns the table as you want it, by splitting the string; and a view on top of that which select * from the function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that I created hope it will help or guid you into solving your requirement:

```
    -- create a temp table to store Letters and their description
    CREATE TABLE #Test1
    (
        ID int identity(1,1),
        Letter varchar(10),
        LetterDescription varchar(100)
    )

    GO 
    --Insert letter into temp table
    INSERT INTO #Test1(Letter, LetterDescription)
    SELECT 'K', 'Youth Motivators'

    INSERT INTO #Test1(Letter, LetterDescription)
    SELECT 'L', 'Other Mentoring'

    INSERT INTO #Test1(Letter, LetterDescription)
    SELECT 'F', 'Gear Up'

    --@Value is just a variable I use to test, your can replace this with a table
    DECLARE @Value VARCHAR(20)
    SELECT @Value = 'K'
    -- SELECT @Value = 'K,L'

    --Query to do the job 
    SELECT @Value AS  AcualChar, 
            CASE WHEN Desc2 IS NULL THEN Desc1 ELSE Desc1 + ','+ Desc2   END AS MentorList
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT T.LetterDescription AS Desc1, y.Desc2 FROM 
        (
            SELECT
            CASE WHEN Charindex(',', @Value) > 0 THEN  Substring(@Value, 1,Charindex(',', @Value)-1) ELSE @Value END AS Letter1

        ) AS L 
        JOIN  #Test1 AS T ON L.Letter1 = T.Letter 

         FULL OUTER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT T.LetterDescription AS Desc2 FROM 
            (
                SELECT
                CASE WHEN Charindex(',', @Value) > 0 THEN Substring(@Value, Charindex(',', @Value)+1, LEN(@Value))  ELSE '' END Letter2
            ) AS L 
            JOIN  #Test1 AS T ON L.Letter2 = T.Letter 
        ) as y ON 1=1
    ) X

    GO
    --Drop the temp table
    DROP TABLE #Test1
```